# RESTful API Server in C#

Tags: c#, api, rest

Are there any frameworks that allow a RESTful API Server to be written in C#?

I have seen MVC 4, however this seems to be providing a view that you can see in the browser, I just require the API server and no view. It would be great if it was able to provide a streaming API too.

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are using .NET Framework 4.5 you can use [Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/)

If you are using .NET Framework 3.5 I highly recommend [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3)

If you are using .NET Core then you can use [ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would I set up my project to use Web API without having to use a view engine?

Comment: I don't think that web api is depending on Razor view engine and it an API only

Answer (score 17):

[Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) is a free REST framework for C#.

Comment: Unfortunately, no longer maintained.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working in .NET 4.0 or higher and looking for a pre-existing REST server solution that you can plug into (which it sounds like you are), you might want to check out [Grapevine](https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine).  You can get it using NuGet, and the [project wiki](https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine/wiki) has lots of sample code.

I am the project author, and I had a similar need as the one you described.  Using resources I found here and elsewhere, I built Grapevine so that I would have a solution in my back pocket whenever I needed it again ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

Answer (score 3):

If you are ok with using IIS to host your app, WebAPI is the route to go, per the above answers.  Not every solution is best in IIS however.

For executable apps (such as a windows service), consider using [WebServicesHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webservicehost(v=vs.110).aspx).   [This page](http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/A-simple-REST-service-in-C.aspx) is a good example of how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

2022, no IIS/ASP answer:

Consider [EmbedIO](https://github.com/unosquare/embedio) (and probably [SWAN](https://github.com/unosquare/swan) on top of that)

> A tiny, cross-platform, module based, MIT-licensed web server for .NET Framework and .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

You can use web api, it is part of the .net MVC framework but it is relying on the razor engine (inly if you use the mvc templating engine cshtml).

If you are using .net 4.0 you can use web api 1,
If you are you .net 4.5 you can use web api 2